# React audio element read metadata

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Component rendering a html5 audio element like this (in the components render method)

```
<audio controls="controls" ref={(input) => {
    input.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        const duration = input.duration;
        console.log("Duration: " + duration);
    }
}}>
    <source src={this.state.audiourl} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

I need to access certain meta information of the audio file after it has been loading and having issues doing this.

As I understood it `ref` would give me a reference to the DOM element and I could therefore attach a function to `onloadedmetadata`. However this approach currently gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onloadedmetadata' of null
```

So input seems to be null. I have read that this is the currently advised appraoch to deal with refs and string refs are deprected.

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use react [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#media-events) for this. Just bind the event listener by passing it as a prop:

```js
<audio 
    controls="controls"
    onLoadedMetadata={event => console.log(event.target.duration)}
    src={this.state.audiourl}
/>
```

Your error happens because react calls inline functions on the `ref` prop first with `null` and then with the DOM element ref. From the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats):

> If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get
>   called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the
>   DOM element. This is because a new instance of the function is created
>   with each render, so React needs to clear the old ref and set up the
>   new one. You can avoid this by defining the ref callback as a bound
>   method on the class, but note that it shouldn’t matter in most cases.